# Asp.Net ApiController - post object contains only zeros

Tags: asp.net, rest, controller

In my api controller I have the following code

```
    public class RunReportController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromUri]string reportname, [FromBody]IsoDate date)
        {
            // the code here is running but the IsoDate is never set correctly
            // reportname is working ok and set to correct values
        }
    }
```

Iso date is declared as follows:

```
public class IsoDate
{
    int Year { get; set; }
    int Month { get; set; }
    int Day { get; set; }

    public IsoDate()
    {
    }
}
```

And this is the way I call it from the page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/admin/report/some-report",
    data: JSON.stringify({Year:2019,Month:1,Day:1}),
    contentType : 'application/json'
}).success(()=>{console.log("ok")}).fail(()=>{console.log("bad")});
```

And this is how the route is declared:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "RunReport", routeTemplate: "api/Admin/Report/{reportname}", defaults: new { controller = "RunReport" });
```

Somehow IsoDate is never assigned any values and always stores 3 zeros. I know I could put the date in the URI but I will need other reports which will take some more complex data (using a different route of course). I need my controllers to accept objects from the body.

Another finding is - if I replace the type of the `date` parameter to `Dictionary<string,int>` is starts to work straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the properties of your class public:

```
public class IsoDate
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }

}
```